# Is there a way to force powershell -Export-CSV cmdlet to maintain a specific column order?

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm new to powershell, so the script is a Frankenstein of various examples of from sites.

My question is how can I make sure that a csv file I am creating for a DataTable keeps the column order I specify?

My script does this to populate the csv headers and values like so:

```
...snip...
$dataTable | ForEach-Object {
            $csv+=New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                program_code=$_.ProgramCode;
                first_name=$_.FirstName;
                last_name=$_.LastName;
                email=$_.email;
                phone=$_.phone;
                phone2=$_.otherphone;
                address=$_.addr1;
                address2=$_.addr2;
                city=$_.city;
                state=$_.state;
                postal_code=$_.Zip;
                country=$_.Country;
                grad_year=$_.HsGradDate;
                lead_date=$_.LeadDate;
                lead_source=$_.LeadSource;
                school_status=$_.SchoolStatus;
        }
        }
    $csv | Export-CSV C:\scripts\NewLeads$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd).csv -notype -Append
...snip...
```

I want the file to have to columns in the order that I specify in the script, but when I open it in notepad or excel the columns appear in a seemingly random order. Keyword being seemingly since they may have some method of ordering themselves.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In PowerShell V3, instead of:

```
        $csv+=New-Object PSObject -Property @{
```

I would use:

```
        $csv+=[pscustomobject]@{
```

The PowerShell V3 parser will preserve the order of the keys when you cast a hash **literal** to either [ordered] or [pscustomobject].  A small side benefit to this approach - it will also be faster.

If you are using V2, you'll need to skip the -Property parameter to New-Object and instead use multiple calls to Add-Member.  It will look something like:

```
$csv+=New-Object PSObject |
    Add-Member -Name program_code -Value $_.ProgramCode -MemberType NoteProperty -PassThru |
    Add-Member -Name first_name -Value $_.FirstName -MemberType NoteProperty -PassThru |
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, both good solutions! Your required a little less typing, which I am a huge fan of.

Comment: Using the [pscustomobject]@{} notation helped immensely over the v2 method, thanks

Answer (score 11):

Select the fields in the order required, then export.

```
$csv | select-object -property program_code,first_name,last_name,email,phone,phone2,address,address2,city,state,psotal_code,country,grad_year,lead_date,lead_source,school_status |
Export-CSV C:\scripts\NewLeads$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd).csv -notype -Append
```

However, you may be able to short-circuit this a little. Depending on what `$dataTable` really is, you may (should, in most cases) be able to select directly from that object and bypass creating the collection of `PSObjects`. But if you need the custom headers, you'll need to use expressions in `select-object` (linebreaks for readability).

```
$dataTable| select-object @{Name="program_code";Expression={$_.ProgramCode}},`
@{Name="first_name";Expression={$_.firstname}},`
@{Name="last_name";Expression={$_.lastname}},email,phone,`
@{Name="phone2";Expression={$_.otherphone}},`
@{Name="addr1";Expression={$_.address}},`
@{Name="addr2";Expression={$_.address2}},city,state,`
@{Name="postal_code";Expression={$_.zip}},country,`
@{Name="grad_year";Expression={$_.hsgraddate}},`
@{Name="lead_date";Expression={$_.leaddate}},`
@{Name="lead_source";Expression={$_.leadsource}},`
@{Name="school_status ";Expression={$_.schoolstatus }}|
 Export-CSV C:\scripts\NewLeads$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd).csv -notype -Append
```